# If $n \circ m$ is monic, can $n$ ever be NOT monic?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

My text book asks me to come up with an example when $n \circ m$ is monic, thoguht $n$ itself is not. Consider following proof:

Given: $(n \circ m) \circ f = (n \circ m) \circ g \implies f = g$ which is the same as $n \circ (m \circ f) = n \circ (m \circ g) \implies f = g$ (associativity, thank you!). Lemma: $\forall k: f = g \implies k \circ f = k \circ g$. By the given lemma $f = g \implies (m \circ f) = (m \circ g)$, which is 
$$n \circ (m \circ f) = n \circ (m \circ g) \implies (m \circ f) = (m \circ g) \implies f = g$$

Clearly, **both** $n, m$ are monics, **thus there exists no case when $m$ is monic and yet $n$ isn't**.

Am I right or my proof is wrong?

Comment: There's a much easier way to prove $f=g$ given $f=g$ than talking about monomorphisms... At any rate, arrows of the form $m\circ f$ can easily be a subset of all arrows that can be precomposed with $n$, but to know if $n$ is a mono we need to know its behavior on arrows outside that subset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **SET**, we have that the includion $m\colon\{a\}\to\{a,b\}$ is monic, the constant map $n\colon \{a,b\}\to\{a\}$ is not monic, and yet $n\circ m$ is monic. For other categories it is often (e.g., when finite direct sums exist) just as easy to come up with similar counterexamples.